# Compilation errors using RestKit

Tags: objective-c, compiler-errors, restkit

I am learning RestKit, and I want to post multi-part data.

```
-(void)publishToServer:(AddTextObj *)aTextObj
{
    NSString *urlString =appDelegate.textUploadURL;
    RKRequestMultipartBody *body = [[RKRequestMultipartBody alloc] init];
    [body addField:"phoneNo" text:aTextObj.phoneNumber];
    [body addField:"name" text:aTextObj.userName];
[body addField:"messageText" text:aTextObj.messageText];
[body addField:"imei" text:aTextObj.imeiNumber];
[body addField:"latitude" text:aTextObj.latitude];
[body addField:"longitude" text:aTextObj.longitude];
[body addField:"messageTitle" text:aTextObj.messageTitle];
[body addField:"picture" image:aTextObj.picture fileName:@"picture.png"];   
[body finalizeBody];
RKRestRequest *rest = [[RKRequest alloc] 
                       initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString] 
                       requestBody:body];
rest.delegate = self;
rest.requestMethod = RKRestRequestPost;
[rest go];
}
```

I'm getting these errors:

1. `RKRequestMultipartBody` undeclared
2. `RKRestRequest` undeclared
3. `RKRestRequestPost` undeclared

Comment: How did you installed RestKit? Did you followed this guide? https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Installing-RestKit-in-Xcode-4.x

Comment: Have you `#import`ed the required header files from RestKit?

Comment: Make sure that you have imported  <Restkit/Restkit.h>

Comment: @mja: Yes, I followed github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Installing-RestKit-in-Xcode-4.x.

Comment: @mattigalloway: I imported "#import <RestKit/RestKit.h>" and I had implemented code to get network status using RKReachabilityObserver and it is working fine.

Comment: May i ask you where you get that code from? I don't think these classes are in the latest 0.9 API nor i see them in latest docs http://restkit.org/api/0.9/

Comment: and I'm also getting error "Can't find protocol declaration for 'RKRestRequestDelegate'. "

Comment: There is no such class in the RestKit's current version. The one you are looking for is probably `RKRequestDelegate`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem is caused by following an outdated tutorial. The classes that cause compilation problem are not in the latest 0.9 API. Please, refer to the most up-to-date Object Mapping guide on [github](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/blob/master/Docs/Object%20Mapping.md).